# Contour/Edge Detection

Tags: python, opencv

I need to detect de edges of just the walls.
Do you guys have any suggestions? Until now I got really poor results and unprecised detections.
These are an example of picture I'm going to use.

[image]

These are multiple houses however in real use only one is going to be in the picture

[image]

```
img = cv.imread('../images/house1.jpeg')

blank = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype="uint8")
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
blur = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 3)

canny = cv.Canny(blur, 100, 200)
cv.imshow("Canny Edges", canny)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 125, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

dilated = cv.dilate(canny, (7, 7), iterations=3)

contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(canny, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(f'{len(contours)} contours found')

cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv.imshow("Contours", blank)
```

That's some of the code I'm testing

Comment: So what is wrong?  Please show your results and explain why it does not work.

Comment: those are 3d prints and you're trying to monitor the progress of each layer... -- you need a laser scanner. topdown camera views simply don't allow you to tell layers apart. just no. others have tried. doesn't work. you'd need _more_ than simply a camera looking down. just use a laser scanner. don't mess around.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i dont need all layers just the area of the top one

Comment: @FilipeCoutinho you could try identifying dark enclosed regions and draw boundaries around them

Comment: from a topdown picture, you will never be able to identify *the top* layer, only surfaces that face upwards, i.e. _any_ layers that are visible. and even that highly depends on the appearance of the deposited material. if it's reflective, reflections are troublesome. if it's dull, like concrete is supposed to be, illumination might just make sky-facing faces appear the same as side walls. again, nothing robust can be done with just a topdown camera and random natural lighting.